# EF concurency tracking when saving changes from a different thread

Tags: .net, entity-framework, concurrency, dbcontext

I have an EF code-first generated database. Data manipulation is done using `DbContext`. An IoC container in Asp.net application generates a `DbContext` instance, that BL objects rely on on a per thread basis. The is a background task class that is loaded along with a web application.

Every one in a while (like every 10 minutes), a background thread adds one item to a list of `Incidents` by calling `myDbContext.Add` within a transaction scope.

Meanwhile, it seems like if one of the `Incidents` is changed by `myDbContext` in a "web requests thread", even though the changes are saved to a database for a moment, they are getting overridden by the set of the `Incidents`, that were pulled by the backgound thread a few moments before the user used the web page to alter an `Incident`.

This seems like a concurrency problem (and I don't implement any concurency like Timestamp columns).

My question is: Shouldn't the background thread only save changed data (in my case, adding a new incident), leaving an entire incidents collection? If it is indeed true, my problem source is somewhere else.

Code from a background thread:

```
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                foreach (var scheduledTask in _db.ScheduledTasks)
                {
                    if (scheduledTask.NextExecuteAfterDate == null)
                    {
                        PopulateNextExecuteAfterDate(scheduledTask);
                        shouldSaveChanges = true;
                    }

                    if (DateTime.Now > scheduledTask.NextExecuteAfterDate)
                    {
                        RegisterRecurringTicket(scheduledTask);
                        CalculateNextTime(scheduledTask);
                        shouldSaveChanges = true;
                    }
                }

                if (shouldSaveChanges) _db.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Complete();
            }
```

The code in subroutine `RegisterRecurringTicket(scheduledTask);` adds item to an Incidents collection. When a `_db.SaveChanges();` is called, it seems like the collection of incidents is overwritten with the older set of incidents, casting the UI-generated changes to an Incidents collection obsolete. If so, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using a `PerThreadScope` `DbContext` injection. This has resulted in an unexpected behaviour of my ASP.NET application. Setting the Ninject Module to resolve `DbContext` in `PerRequestScope` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply calling `myDbContext.Incidents.ToList()` will not cause anything to be overwritten in the database. *However*, I could easily imagine a situation like this:

```
// My Incident tracker
IEnumerable<Incident> CurrentIncidents {get{return myDbContext.Incidents.ToList();}}

// Meanwhile, in another class on the same thread...
foreach(var incident in IncidentTracker.CurrentIncidents)
{
   var claims = myDbContext.Claims.Where(c => c.IncidentId == incident.IncidentId);
   foreach(var claim in claims)
   {
      Process(claim);
   }
   incident.Processed = true;
}
myDbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In the above example, even though you're not pulling the `Incident`s directly from the `myDbContext`, since both classes got the same context injected into them, calling `SaveChanges()` actually affects both the claims (which you wanted to change) and the incidents (which you didn't).

Is it possible that something like this is happening?

Comment: Yes. I have written an updated to the question body, since I have discovered, that I have misinformed question readers about a problem setup. Please take a look.